# Service Applications required by Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2013, tfs-2015

We are in the process of the installing and configuring TFS 2015. Part of it, I am installing SharePoint 2013 on the same box as TFS. I don't want to create all service applications given by Configuration wizard as it slows down the server. I just want to create bare minimum which are required by TFS.

Anyone knows exact list which service apps used by TFS?

Comment: You don't need to install SharePoint to use TFS. In fact, I commonly recommend against it. The features you gain by integrating Sharepoint with TFS are largely inferior to the core reporting and dashboard features that are in the box with TFS 2015.

Comment: The requirement is to have SharePoint; it's a business decision and I cannot go against it.

Comment: It's worth having a discussion around that business requirement, because you can use Sharepoint for document management as a separate, non-integrated tool and not lose anything important. Sharepoint is a nightmare to upgrade and is typically a major pain point when upgrading TFS.